# How do I install Python packages in Jupyter notebook running from WSL2+ubuntu20.04

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running jupyter notebook from WSL2+Ubuntu20.04. However, the jupyter notebook image does not include many package.

For instance, I would like to install pandas and append sys path accordingly.

(UPDATE)
Based on the recommendation of Prayson, I did the following from Jupytr notebook terminal:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade --user pip 
python3 -m pip install --user pandas
```

Both steps ran successfully. Then I could call the following code snipper successfully for the FIRST TIME only:
I ran the following code snippet:

```
import sys

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

However, when I shut down and restarted again, I could not import pandas again and I am getting following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-df58772bf04b> in <module>
      7 
      8 import numpy as np
----> 9 import pandas as pd
     10 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     11 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

I may be missing adding path. However, I am not sure how to do it correctly.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Update your pip

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are installing packages in the correct environment. From the code trace above, it appears that Pandas is installed in environment serving Jupyter server.

```py
import sys

# upgrade pip and install package
!{sys.executable} -m pip install –upgrade pip && !{sys.executable} -m pip install package
```

The above code, makes sure that a package is install in the environment that you are currently in session.

You can open `terminal` session in Jupyter that will give you assess to shell. I would recommend installing packages there as you would in normal terminal. See [Jupyter Documentation for how to access terminal](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/terminal.html)

Comment: Thanks. Though I was able to upgrade pip, I was still not able to install PANDAS. Please have a  look at the updated question. Using terminal did not help.

Comment: What happens when you drop `—user`?

Comment: I initially thought that it worked. However, when I closed the window and then tried to run the same code, I am unable to import pandas. Pease help me.

Comment: Have you tried to access the terminal from Jupyter as the documentation showed above?

Comment: Yes, I did that. Please have a look at the updated question. It may be just that I am not adding necessary path. However, I do not know how to do it correctly. Thanks a lot for your willingness to help me.

Comment: In Jupyter check print `sys.executable`. Go on terminal and do `which python3`. Do they point to the same Python?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226362/discussion-between-prayson-w-daniel-and-garima-singh).

Answer (score 1):

You just need to install the package from the terminal, no need to do anything in Jupyter.

To install pandas, type in terminal:

`pip install pandas`

Now import in jupyter, it will work fine.

Also, no need to use sudo.

Comment: Please see the updated question. I installed using the terminal and  could successfully import the first time. However, when I shut down and restarted docker and then Jupyter, I can not import it again. It seems that I may have to add path correctly. However, I do not know how to do it correctly. Your willingness to help is highly appreciated,

Comment: Try importing from the terminal. Open terminal, type `python3`. In the python interpreter, try to import the package, is it importing or giving error?

Comment: Also, kindly check the working directory for your notebook. Run the following code in your python interpreter and jupyter notebook and post the output. `import os; os.getcwd()`